# Panel not scrollable when set to layout: 'vbox' and contains dynamic fieldset

Tags: sencha-touch

Here's the view below folks, I don't know if it's the dynamic content that's hurting me here (that inner fieldset gets loaded at runtime) or that I've done something wrong with the vbox layout as a whole.

Basically the content gets truncated when it runs out of screen on the device.

Really new to sencha...

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ScanEvent.Edit', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.scanEventEdit',
    xtype: 'scanEventEdit',
    config: {
        title: 'Scan Event',
        layout: 'vbox',
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'map',
                name: 'scanEventMap',
                flex: 1,
                useCurrentLocation: true,
                mapOptions: {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    zoom: 14
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                name: 'scanEventFieldset',
                flex: 2,
                title: 'Scan Event Details',
                defaults: {
                    labelWidth: '40%',
                    labelWrap: true
                },
                items: []
            },
            {
                xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                name: 'latitude'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                name: 'longitude'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'submitScanEventButton',
                name: 'submitScanEventButton',
                margin: 20,
                padding: 8,
                text: 'Continue',
                action: 'acceptScanEvent',
                iconCls: 'arrow_right',
                iconAlign: 'right'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: so if you push content dynamically then only scroll problems occurs or here is an issue of scroll.

Comment: either, dynamic fields or if i turn off the dynamic load and just throw a bunch of text fields out there to force a scroll it still doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If in fieldset where you are adding items,  scroll is not coming then you can add scrollable: true property in fieldset also to see all added items.

Comment: That's one of the many, many things I've tried to get this working but no luck, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: which version are you using?